# Hola a todos soy nuevo en Laravel, como podría hacer 2 formularios por el momento solo tengo 1 formulario pero quiero otro

Tags: laravel-8

Por lo que tengo entendido tengo que hacer otro controlador o puedo ocupar el mismo de mi primer formulario es lo que no se?

Comment: Tu comentario en un poco vago, deberias de poner el código de como generas el formulario para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Pon tu codigo y lo que queires hacer